# PowerAutomate - Array elements can only be selected using an integer index

Tags: power-automate

I am collecting data from an excel sheet.
This data is addded in a Word formula on sharepoint.
But only the word files are created correctly with the name, but the formula is empty.
In the end I receive an error:
"Array elements can only be selected using an integer index."

This is the flow:

[image]

And here is the test where the error occurs:

[image]

And here the Output (files are created but empty):

[image]

EDIT:
Another thing I just recognized is that when I edit the field in grid view this values aren't in the world file when I open it:

Sharepoint:

[image]
Word:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't your `Update word file properties` action be in the first `For each`?
Drag and drop it below the `Create word file from trend signals` action then double check you are referencing the right properties.